# Nginx server installs fine, but then doesn't do anything

Tags: server, nginx

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu LTS 16.04 server, being hosted on Amazon. [According to instructions on the web](http://idroot.net/linux/install-nginx-ubuntu-16-04/), installing Nginx is this easy:

1. `apt-get install nginx`
2. `sudo systemctl enable nginx`
3. `sudo systemctl start nginx`

At this point, according to all instructions I've seen, I should be able to open a browser, go to my IP address, and see the default "**Welcome to Nginx**" page.

But when I open a browser and go to my IP address, I get no response at all. If I try to access that IP address from a command line to see if I can get a more verbose output, I get this response:

```
$ wget --verbose http://###.###.###.###:80
--2016-11-11 00:26:57--  http://###.###.###.###/
Connecting to ###.###.###.###:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

There is nothing in the `access.log`, there is only one line in the `error.log`:

`2016/11/10 08:03:41 [notice] 30097#30097: signal process started`

And I used `ufw` to open port 80:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Why is Nginx not doing anything, and how do I get it to show the default welcome page?

Comment: Have you opened up the EC2 security group by adding HTTP to the allow list?

Comment: @bc2946088, thank you for responding. The server was not created by me, I was only tasked with installing the software from the Ubuntu level of things. I just looked up EC2 security, and I see it's an Amazon specific setting. I will contact the person with access to the Amazon settings... if you have a specific recommendation for what I need to tell them, that would be very helpful.

Comment: They'll know exactly where it's at, or they shouldn't be in charge of it.  Security groups are essentially virtual firewalls, and by default they are quiet restricted.  They simply need to open up port 80 to your ec2 instance.

Comment: @bc2946088, thank you, the EC2 security settings turned out to be the problem, and the person in charge changed it for me. If you put your comments into an answer, I'll mark it correct.